Inconsistent error behaviour on recursive Typescript type
I have a type that allows to describe any path through an object from the top (root) properties down to every child property in the object as a string array.

It shall allow to stop at any level
It shall not allow to select sibling or ancestor nodes in the next step, only direct children
If a property of the object holds an array, it shall allow to select an array entry
either via a predicate function or a numeric index

This is the type:
export type PredicateFunction<ArrayType> = (array: ArrayType, index?: number) => boolean;
export type IndexOrPredicateFunction<Type> = number | PredicateFunction<Type>;
export type StatePathKey = IndexOrPredicateFunction<any> | string;

export type StatePath<Obj, Path extends (string | IndexOrPredicateFunction<any>)[] = []> =
    object extends Required<Obj>
        ? Path
        : Obj extends object
            ? (Path |
                    // Check if object is array
                    (Obj extends readonly any[] ?
                        // ...when array only allow index or PredicateFunction
                        StatePath<Obj[number], [...Path, IndexOrPredicateFunction<Obj[number]>]>
                        // ...when object generate type of all possible keys
                        : { [Key in string & keyof Obj]: StatePath<Obj[Key], [...Path, Key]> }[string & keyof Obj]))
            : Path;

It works regarding type checks - it will detect and error out for all invalid paths but the error behavior makes me believe that something is not correct.
Assume this interface:
interface State  {
    test: {
        branch1: {
            branch1_1: {
                branch1_2: string;
            }
        },
        branch2: { 
            branch2_1: {
                branch2_2: string;
            }
        }
    }
}

Now I define those consts:
const test1: StatePath<State> = ['test', "branch1", "justAnyString"];  // <- Error on array entry
const test2: StatePath<State> = ['test', "branch1", "branch2_1"]; // <- Error on const

Why do I get different errors?
The behavior can be observed here:
Typescript playground

So there's nothing wrong with your type or TS's checking of it, right? You're just unhappy about IntelliSense, correct? Well this is a missing TS feature described at ms/TS#38603. If you want to see that changed then you might want to give it a , but nothing we do to the type is going to fix it. You can maybe write a helper function but it's going to be clunky, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Ok I thought intellisense (and other autocompletion tools) are based on the typechecks and won't suggest invalid types - I'm confused now :) I upvoted the issue.
But why does the transpiler give different errors for the two described cases?

Looks like it at first gets the wrong information that "branch1_1" | "branch2_1" are allowed values for the position in the array. And only when I fill in the invalid value it checks against the complete tuple

• Please [edit] the question to include all relevant code as plaintext and not just in a playground link. • Ah, this is essentially two different questions; one is "inconsistent error behavior" which is not a bug or a missing feature, it's just how TS errors work; if you want [0, 1] | [1, 0] and I give you [0, 0], then neither element is itself in error, it's the whole thing. But if I give you [0, 2] then you know the 2 is wrong. The other question is about intellisense as per ms/TS#38603. Please [edit] to ask just one of these and I'll answer it.

Ok edited. I think I got it, when checking single entries against a tuple union, typescript cannot consider only the specific tuples matching for the path but only all entries at the specific position in all tuples. And only when it finally maches the tuple as a whole, it fails.

So slowly I'm giving up on building the type that initially seemed so simple. Are you ready for the master question on how to build that exact type? :-D

Maybe? But if it turns out that the type you have is correct and you just don't like TS's IntelliSense I'm not sure what could be done there.

This can be demonstrated without the recursive type. Let's observe the behavior of a simple union of two tuple types:
type X = ['test', 'branch1', 'branch1_1'] | ['test', 'branch2', 'branch2_1'];

When you try to assign an invalid value with an element that doesn't match any of the types for that position in the union members of the type, you get an error for that element:
const test1: X = ['test', "branch1", "justAnyString"]; // error!
//                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '"justAnyString"' is not assignable to type '"branch1_1" | "branch2_1"'.

That's because the error really and truly can be attributed to that element. On the other hand, when you assign an invalid value where each element matches at least one of the types for that position in the union members of the type, you get an error on the assignment instead:
const test2: X = ['test', "branch1", "branch2_1"]; // error!
//    ~~~~~ 
// Type '["test", "branch1", "branch2_1"]' is not assignable to type 'X'.

That's because the error cannot be isolated to a single element. It's a matter of opinion, not fact, whether "branch2_1" is wrong (and should be "branch1_1") or whether "branch1" is wrong (and should be "branch2"). TypeScript doesn't try to determine which member of the union you were going for, it just says "this doesn't match" and moves along.  You could argue that TypeScript should assume that earlier elements in the tuple are "more correct" than later ones, but someone else could argue differently.
Anyway, that explains the difference in the error locations. I wouldn't say it's  inconsistent; you have two different categories of mistake, and TypeScript displays an error in two different ways.

Note that this is not specific to tuples. You get the same error behavior for arbitrary object types:
type Y = { a: string, b: number } | { a: number, b: string }
const y1: Y = { a: "abc", b: true }; // error!
//                        ~
const y2: Y = { a: "abc", b: "def" }; // error!
//    ~~

Again, for y1, the b property is definitely incorrect. No member of the Y union allows a boolean-valued property for b, so TypeScript warns on the b property. But for y2, no single member is definitely incorrect. The a property can be a string and the b property can be a string; they just can't both be a string at the same time. So TypeScript warns on the assignment, not the property.
Playground link to code

Thank you for the explanation.
This is not transparent for the user. He doesn't know the order of checks and how the internals of the transpiler work so at best it's bad user experience if you have two different error types for something the user cannot distinguish. And regarding intellisense I would bluntly call it a bug and not a missing feature. If it makes suggestions which don't take into consideration all possible errors, it's broken.

For the object type it's different, because it cannot be inferred which one of the properties is wrong. So I would expect that behavior as a user.

Thanks for all of your works and answers btw, this critic is directed to Typescript not your answer :-D
