Non recursive type to navigate through an object via a string array
Coming from this question and requirements: Type to navigate through object
I gave up with the recursive approaches and trying to build the type in a non-recursive fashion. If somebody still wants to try his luck with recursion, please answer in the other question.
Something like this came up my mind, but it breaks after the first ArrayIndex, I guess Typescript cannot infer what the next key is:
export type StatePath<
    State,
    Key1 extends keyof State,
    Type1 extends (State[Key1] extends (infer Type1)[] ? Type1 : State[Key1]),
    ArrayIndex2 extends (State[Key1] extends (infer Type1)[] ? [(number | PredicateFunction<Type1>)] : []),
    Key2 extends keyof Type1,
    Type2 extends (Type1[Key2] extends (infer Type2)[] ? Type2 : Type1[Key2]),
    ArrayIndex3 extends (Type1[Key2] extends (infer Type2)[] ? [(number | PredicateFunction<Type2>)] : []),
    Key3 extends keyof Type2,
    Type3 extends (Type2[Key3] extends (infer Type3)[] ? Type3 : Type2[Key3]), ...
> =
    | [Key1]
    | [Key1, ...ArrayIndex2]
    | [Key1, ...ArrayIndex2, Key2]
    | [Key1, ...ArrayIndex2, Key2, ...ArrayIndex3]
    | [Key1, ...ArrayIndex2, Key2, ...ArrayIndex3, Key3]
    ...

export interface TestState {
    test1: {
        test2: {
            test3: string[];
        };
        test4: {
            test5: string
        };
    }
}

const test: StatePath<TestState> = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

Grateful for any ideas!

"I gave up with the recursive approaches" - why? This absolutely should use recursion. Please show us your attempts!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78997448/inconsistent-error-behaviour-on-recursive-typescript-type/78999922#78999922
Whenever I touch recursion with Typescript for possibly large structures it renders my language service unusable or other things pop up hat make it unusable.

What's PredicateFunction? Please make sure the code is a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to work with. (note: "look at the other question" isn't sufficient; any code/information that's necessary should be contained here as plaintext, although links to source material are nice supplements)

(see prev comment).  My approach would use recursion, but you can always manually unroll a recursive type as shown in this playground link. I don't know if that meets all your needs (your requirements are not listed here, and they are not accompanied by test cases so it's hard to know if we've met them, you should [edit] any such requirements into this question and provide test inputs to demonstrate them) but I'm happy to write up an answer explaining if it addresses the question fully. Let me know.

@jcalz thank you, would that be possible in one type (like the example)?

Why does that matter? What's the use case where you need "one type" for it to work? (Your example doesn't make a lot of sense because it requires a bunch of inputs, so I'm not sure what you're trying to salvage of that.) Also, please do the edits I asked for so we can proceed.

(see prev comment, pls address the points there.) Putting it into a single type is very taxing on the compiler, probably worse than the recursive definition, as shown in this playground link. Without a good reason for why you need one type, I'd say it's not worth it. Please let me know how you want to move forward.
